# Capybara input button is not clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In my Capybara test I want to test signing in a user. Unfortunately the submit button

```
<input class="btn btn-success" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
```

is not clicked. Here is my capybara test:

```
it 'shows an error message for wrong credentials' do
    visit "/"
    expect(page).to have_content("Sign In")
    click_link "Sign In"

    fill_in "Email", with: "wrong_email"
    fill_in "Password", with: "wrong_password"
    click_button "Sign In"

    expect(page).to have_content("Password and Email do not match!")
end
```

I do not get an error message but the content is not to be found on the page. Following the test case on the live page shows the error message I expect.

Comment: You can use selenium so that you can view the page visually while test case execution. It will help you to know the issue

Comment: Thanks that helped me figuring it out. I had a Sign Up button in my navbar and in my sign up form. Capybara clicked on the wrong button.

Comment: Please add your comment as the answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: I will mark it as correct in two days. It is not eligible now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured my problem with the help of [@RAJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30390733/capybara-input-button-is-not-clicked?noredirect=1#comment48870901_30390733). My page had two buttons with the same text ('Sign In') and the button to go to the sign in form was clicked. Not the button to actually Sign In the user.

To solve this issue I added an ID to the submit button and replaced

```
click_button 'Sign In'
```

with:

```
page.find('#submit').click
```

which resolved the issue.